# ffmpeg volume levels

Tags: ffmpeg

I AM USING WINDOWS

I did recording camera,microphone and system sounds each separately with ffmpeg.

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="USB2.0 PC CAMERA" output.mkv
```

Above code for camera recording.

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i audio="@device_cm_{33D9A762-90C8-11D0-BD43-00A0C911CE86}\wave_{5B4DB0B5-B645-4AFA-930D-4710AAF753DB}" output.wav
```

And above for microphone.

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i audio="@device_cm_{33D9A762-90C8-11D0-BD43-00A0C911CE86}\wave_{ADECEC1D-C3CC-4BAE-8516-752251B8B63F}" output.mkv
```

And above for system audio.

I mixed system audio with microphone like below:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i audio="@device_cm_{33D9A762-90C8-11D0-BD43-00A0C911CE86}\wave_{5B4DB0B5-B645-4AFA-930D-4710AAF753DB}" -f dshow -i audio="@device_cm_{33D9A762-90C8-11D0-BD43-00A0C911CE86}\wave_{ADECEC1D-C3CC-4BAE-8516-752251B8B63F}" -filter_complex amerge=inputs=2 stream.mp3
```

BUT there is still issue to volume levels. How do I adjust sound volume levels
for each input or output file?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the [volume](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#volume) filter:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i audio="@device_cm_{33D9A762-90C8-11D0-BD43-00A0C911CE86}\wave_{5B4DB0B5-B645-4AFA-930D-4710AAF753DB}" -f dshow -i audio="@device_cm_{33D9A762-90C8-11D0-BD43-00A0C911CE86}\wave_{ADECEC1D-C3CC-4BAE-8516-752251B8B63F}" -filter_complex "[0:a]volume=0.3[a0];[1:a]volume=0.5[a1];[a0][a1]amerge=inputs=2" -ac 1 stream.mp3
```

Comment: I made mistake about mixing and merging. Merging is for collecting many channels into one stream. But it is mixing what I was looking for with one stream with one channel in output.

Comment: @joshjoyer I added `-ac 1` to the answer to create one channel in output.